# How can I create with base64 tokens automatically for my products?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I building with ruby on rails and I want to generate unique Base64 tokens for my model automatically. In all the examples I've seen, the token is generate for the name or a password. How can I generate tokens in general?

My model looks something like this:

```
{        
  "id": 2,
  "name": "cookies",
  "description": "box 150g",
  "logo_url": null,
  "token": null
}
```

Comment: What do you need this token for? Read about `before_create` activerecord hook.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply generate a random URL-safe base64 string using [`SecureRandom#urlsafe_base64`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.2/libdoc/securerandom/rdoc/SecureRandom.html#method-c-urlsafe_base64) and populate the `token` field.

```
before_create :generate_token

def generate_token
  self.token ||= SecureRandom.urlsafe_base64
end
```